# The costs of using existing 6 axis kuka/abb robots and existing vision systems in picking and placing tasks

Tags: industrial-robot

I would like to use a Kuka/abb 6 axis robot and a machine vision system to pick and place a variety of metal drill bits in size ranges from 0.5mm (ascending up 0.5mm per cylinde) to 13mm in metric and then 1/16 of an inch ascending to 9/64 of an inch. The machine would not have to differentiate between the bits, niether drill bit would weight more than 1kg.

Crucially at the beginning and end of the picking and placing I would like to inspect the very tip of the cylinders to be inspected for a 118 degree chamfer on one end of the bit which should be present regardless of drill diameter of length.

I am lead to believe that if the drill bits are placed end up on a conveyor belt and always the the same place its relatively low cost but crucially if the kuka 6 axis robot has to find the drill bits then the cost increases dramatically, is this true?

Comment: I would be happy to arrange the drill bits sharp side down so they could be 'picked up' with the use of a traditional drill press chuck which could be tightened and loosened automatically. Though I have no idea how this would be controlled and monitor.

Comment: By cost if you mean financial cost, then yes it is true.